# Is this use of 'have' grammatical?

Tags: grammar

> I think for those of us who have jobs and have been working for some time ***have*** this habit of telling ourselves that we deserve to take the money that we earn and spend it on things that we like.

What's the subject of bolded 'have'? The structure feels weird to me. All I've been heard was some things like "I think for those of us who + Verb, Subject + Verb" such as follows.

> I think for those of us who live here in New England, it's uplifting to see what a New England story this is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I do not think this sentence is set up well, for exactly the reason you point out - there is no clear subject for **have.**

I think there are two edits that would fix this issue, either replace **for** with **that**:

> I think **that** those of us who have jobs and have been working for some time **have** this habit of telling ourselves that we deserve to take the money that we earn and spend it on things that we like.

OR

add a comma and **we**

> I think for those of us who have jobs and have been working for some time, **we have** this habit of telling ourselves that we deserve to take the money that we earn and spend it on things that we like.